# python platform doesn't recognized Ubuntu distribution

Tags: python, ubuntu, platform, software-distribution

When I run a compiled by hand Python3, `platform.linux_distribution()` doesn't recognize Ubuntu distribution and think it's a Debian :

```
$ /opt/python3.4/bin/python3.4
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('debian', 'jessie/sid', '')
```

But when I use the Python3 shipped with Ubuntu, I get :

```
$ /usr/bin/python3
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('Ubuntu', '14.04', 'trusty')
```

What do we need to make it recognize Ubuntu distributions?

Comment: What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: `Linux enacit1pc4 3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:27:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: is `platform.linux_distribution()` native code? You could debug it and see what sh command it exactly execs

Comment: @deathangel908 - it doesn't execute any sh code, that wouldn't make sense. It tries to get the release from /etc/lsb-release and other suitable locations.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu fixes it for himself in the file `/usr/lib/python3.4/platform.py` by checking first the content of the file `/etc/lsb-release` before looking for files `/etc/*[-_][release|version]`.
This prevent from thinking this is a Debian (as said by the file `/etc/debian_version`) when it's in fact an Ubuntu (which is based on Debian).

I could fix it by patching that file with the one provided on an Ubuntu.